# Python Nose Annotations

Tags: python, nose

I want to label each individual test case with annotations `@SmokeTest` or `@LoadTest` `@RegressionTest` or `@LongRunningTest`.

Will it be possible to categorize each test case into one of the following categories, using Python nose that provide annotations?

1. Smoke Test
2. Load Test
3. Regression
4. Long Running Test
   I want to add label to each individual test cases please provide your suggestions. 
   http://pythontesting.net/framework/nose/nose-introduction/

Answer (score 2):

Add attributes using `@attr`. `@attr` can be set for classes as well the same way as below if you want to run the whole class

Refer: http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html

```
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr

@attr('smoke')
def test_awesome_1():
    # your test...
@attr('load')
def test_awesome_2():
    # your test...
@attr('regression')
def test_awesome_3():
    # your test...
@attr('regression')
def test_awesome_4():
    # your test...
```

and then run it as

```
nosetests -a 'smoke'            #Runs test_awesome_1 only
nosetests -a 'load'             #Runs test_awesome_2 only
nosetests -a 'regression'       #Runs test_awesome_3 and test_awesome_4
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking, but it sounds like you might be looking for [the built-in `nose` plugin 'Attrib'](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html) which lets you set attributes for tests (and select groups of tests based on attributes).

Answer (score 0):

Add attributes using `@attr` to label test cases, and classes as well, with annotations:

```
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr

    @attr(priority='first')
    def test_support_1():
        #test details...

    @attr(priority='second')
    def test_support_2():
        #test details...
```

Run it as:

```
nosetests -a priority=first
nosetests -a priority=second
```

In Python 2.6 and higher, `@attr` can be set on classes as below:

```
    @attr(priority='sanity')
    class MyTestCase:
       def test_support_1(self):
         pass
       def test_support_2(self):
         pass
```

Run it as:

```
nosetests -a priority=sanity
```